# accessing lists values of dictionary

Tags: python

I created a dictionary of lists using:

```
names = defaultdict(list)
```

I am reading a line from the text file, splitting it into 3 columns. I am making the first column of the line as key and other two columns as the values in a list. I used the following code segment as following:

```
with open('f.txt') as f:
    lines = [l.split() for l in f.readlines() if l.strip()]
    for l in lines:
            names[l[0]].append([l[1],l[2]])
```

I have the text files like this:

```
00:12:34:23:45:67       134     123.456

45:34:23:45:44:23       133     345.123

3f:32:dr:45:34:r5       133     212.345

00:12:34:23:45:67       134     555.555

00:12:34:23:45:67       136     555.556

00:12:34:23:45:67       134     555.560
```

If i run my program to output key:value pairs, the output is:

```
00:12:34:23:45:67 [['134', '123.456'], ['134', '555.555'], ['136', '555.556'], ['134', '555.560']]

45:34:23:45:44:23 [['133', '345.123']]

3f:32:dr:45:34:r5 [['133', '212.345']]
```

How can I access the individual elements of the list? For example, in this output, I want to count number of 133, 134, 135, 136 of each key and the time difference between each type. For example, for the key `00:12:34:23:45:67`, there are 3 134's, 1 136. The time difference between highest of and lowest of 134's for that key is 555.560-123.456. I want this result for all 133,134,135,136 types. I am struggling for this problem from many days. please help. Much appreciated.

Comment: how do i accept the answers? which button to click?

Comment: The checkmark next to the best answer.

Comment: accepted answers for my previous posts. thank you for informing me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a better data structure is in order here...

```
from collections import defaultdict
names=defaultdict(lambda :defaultdict(list))

with open('f.txt') as f:
   lines = [l.split() for l in f.readlines() if l.strip()]
   for l in lines:
       names[l[0]][l[1]].append(float(l[2]))
```

Now, to get the counts and differences from max/min:

```
for k,v in names.items():
    for kk,vv in v.items():
        print k,kk,len(vv),max(vv)-min(vv)
```

Output:

```
00:12:34:23:45:67 136 1 0.0
00:12:34:23:45:67 134 3 432.104
45:34:23:45:44:23 133 1 0.0
3f:32:dr:45:34:r5 133 1 0.0
```

Comment: +1, but may I suggest unpacking `l` into `name, val1, val2` or something similar?

Comment: I agree that the data structure proposed in the question was making things difficult.

Comment: i am getting an error: "'list' object has no attribute 'items'"

Comment: @senderle : I agree that unpacking here is probably better, but that would fail if the datafile had 4+ fields (e.g. if there is some way to specify comments or something), but I can't be completely sure so I left it the way it was.

Comment: @user1411416 : That's strange -- I copied it directly from here and re-ran it and it worked. (python 2.6, OS-X) -- I did remove the blank lines from your datafile, but that shouldn't matter since you already take care of those in your list-comp.

Answer (score 0):

To compute the counts you can do the following:

```
counts = {}
for key, values in names.items():
    for v in values:
        if v[0] in counts:
            counts[v[0]] += 1
        else:
            counts[v[0]] = 1
```